# Css properties collides between two react component

Tags: css, reactjs

I have two Components and two css file for each component. css file is imported in req component. The problem is each component has same classnames and if i changes css in component it's effecting the other component with same class too.. Pls help.. comment if you don't understand my question

Comment: Consider a scoped CSS-in-JS solution such as [JSS](https://cssinjs.org/), which you can use to generate unique class names per component.

Comment: ok. but why this happens?

Comment: Because CSS was originally designed to style documents with text and a few pictures, not complex single-page apps based on components. Due to this, everything in CSS is global by default. To scope it locally, you have to use shadow DOM, iframes, or simply ensure that class names do not overlap. The CSS-in-JS approach is an automated way of ensuring that, but you can also try manual approaches such as [BEM](http://getbem.com/introduction/).

Answer (score 0):

```css
html { 
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

/* 
This rule is not needed ↷
p { 
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
*/
```

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

/* 
This rule is not needed ↷
p a {
  line-height: 1.5;
}
*/
```

About the css priority level,

1. Basically, the css that follows has a higher priority.
2. !important> inline style attribute> id> class, other attributes, capital class (like :first-child)> tag element, capital element (like ::before) in order of priority.
3. If the priorities are the same, the css with a larger number have higher priority.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

If it is not inside and is imported, the priority is the same.
And because of the inheritance, cascade of css, it will affect if you define p even if it's a different file.

---

There are also css methodologies such as BEM, SMACSS, and OOCSS. However, this also does not solve the fundamental problem.

> From CSS methodologies such as BEM and Atomic CSS through to programmatically encapsulated CSS modules, many are doing their best to sidestep or otherwise suppress these features. This gives developers more control over their CSS, but only an autocratic sort of control based on frequent intervention.

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/11/css-inheritance-cascade-global-scope-new-old-worst-best-friends/

There are options such as shadow dom, but polyfill is also directly linked to performance issues.

If you're using react, I think the approach taken by the next's attitude that is looking at about css is probably the closest to the current best we can see.

I hope you have a look at the way css is divided in next.

https://nextjs.org/